# How to include static files into the lambda package with AWS SAM esbuild?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, esbuild

I have a NodeJS AWS Lambda function which generates an e-mail based on a html template file (`emailTemplate.html`). I started [building my lambdas with esbuild via SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build-typescript.html). Now I wonder how I can configure SAM/esbuild to include this file into my lambda package.

This is the SAM template configuration for the lambda:

```yaml
  EmailNotificationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./lambdas-node/email-notifications/
      Handler: daily-summary.handler
      Timeout: 120
      MemorySize: 512
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - daily-summary.ts
```

In my application code, I read the file from the local file system:

```js
fs.readFileSync("./emailTemplate.html", "utf-8")
```

The html file is small so I'd like to stick to this minimalistic approach. I can always fetch the file from S3 or package it in a layer but I prefer not to go there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so basically ESBuild's [file loader](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#file) is the way to go. ESBuild will replace the import with a reference to the file and copy over the file to the result bundle. (That's exactly what I wanted.)

This behaviour seems rather specific to ESBuild and will not work with the regular `tsc` compiler. So I replaced my build step to typechecking with `tsc` and transpiling with `esbuild` (see below)

I added an import to the html file to my code. This will ESBuild trigger to do something with this file.

```js
import emailTemplateHtmlUrl from "./emailTemplate.html";
```

To keep the typechecker happy, I added also a `types.d.ts` file (mind the `d.ts` extension)

```js
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

And then I added the `Loader` to my SAM template so that ESBuild will copy over html files and reference them in the import:

```yaml
  EmailNotificationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./lambdas-node/email-notifications/
      Handler: daily-summary.handler
      Timeout: 120
      MemorySize: 512
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Sourcemap: true
        Loader:
          - .html=file
        EntryPoints:
          - daily-summary.ts
```

And finally, my new test command looks now like this:

```bash
tsc --noEmit
npx esbuild daily-summary.ts --outdir=. --loader:.html=file --platform=node 
--bundle
mocha *.spec.js
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  For anybody using this with .json files and not wanting to pull in package.json, you can set up a composite suffix like ".config.json" and that works with this method.